# KeyBinding not working with RelayCommand

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I'm using a slightly adapted [RelayCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) to direct commands to my view model and this works fine, but for some reason, I can't get input bindings to work at all. For example, I have a menu like this:

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource app}">
...
    <MenuItem Header="_Run" IsEnabled="{Binding HasScript}">
        <MenuItem Header="_Run" Command="{ Binding RunCommand }" Style="{StaticResource menuEnabledStyle}" InputGestureText="F5"/>
        ...
    </MenuItem>
</Grid>
```

This runs fine when you click the menu item (obviously), but I have the shortcut defined here:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F5"
                Command="{Binding RunCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Alt" Key="F4"
                Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

But hitting F5 does nothing (for reference, the binding to `ApplicationCommands.Close` works just fine). There are no binding errors (if I change it to bind the non-existent `FooCommand` I immediately get a binding error) and I can't figure out what it's missing here.

My command is defined in my view model like this:

```
private RelayCommand _runCommand;
public ICommand RunCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_runCommand == null)
        {
            _runCommand = new RelayCommand(p => { this.CurrentScript.Run(); }, p => this.CurrentScript != null && !this.CurrentScript.IsRunning);
        }
        return _runCommand;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to initialise your command in your ViewModel Constructor, you could have a `private set`

Comment: @XAMlMAX: It's lazy initialized right there when you first try to access it (in the `get`)

Comment: I've had similar issue, once I initialized it in my constructor everything started working.

Comment: @XAMlMAX: Ok, I'll give it a try. Edit: didn't seem to help. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @J.H.: As it happens I have another one that has no `canExecute` and that one doesn't work either `_openCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.Open());`

Comment: Is it because the Menu's parent Grid has the DataContext set but the Window doesn't?

Comment: @J.H. I thought that might be an issue, but a) I get no binding errors and b) I can't set the data context of the window because `app` is defined in `<Window.Resources>` so I can't bind it to `<Window>`

Comment: Try: <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="{Binding RunCommand, Source={StaticResource app}}" />

Comment: @J.H. Ha! That does work. Thanks. If you write an answer I'll accept it. I am confused as to why it needed be to specify told the source since it wasn't giving me binding errors before, but if it's running, it's running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Command's Binding doesn't have a data context (well, its using the windows but it isn't set). So, you have to specify it.

Here is the complete, working test case I made:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication30.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication30"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:VM x:Key="app" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="{Binding RunCommand, Source={StaticResource app}}" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource app}">
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Run" Command="{Binding RunCommand}" InputGestureText="F5" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS:

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.MVVM;

namespace WpfApplication30
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class VM
    {
        private RelayCommand _runCommand;
        public RelayCommand RunCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_runCommand == null)
                {
                    _runCommand = new RelayCommand(p => { MessageBox.Show("RunCommand"); });
                }
                return _runCommand;
            }
        }
    }
}
```